# Validate on custom words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field in my form, that should not accept some specific words(www, ftp, smtp, etc). Is there any validator that could make some kind of black listed words, that can not be written to db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
validates :subdomain, :exclusion => { :in => %w(www ftp smtp) }
```

ref: [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#exclusion)

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own black list validator.
The syntax could be

```
validates :field, :black_list => {:file_path => "/path/to/words_file"}
```

Your validator will look to each word in the `/path/to/words_file` file and add errors on your model if the attribute `field` contains one black listed word.

Comment: this would work aswell, but Emrah provided more easy way to achieve what i need.

Comment: Yes it depends on how many words you want to black list. If you have a lot you will pollute your model with unnecessary data, however if you juste have 5-7 words Emrah's solution works fine.